# How to read email headers?

Tags: email, email-headers

Can someone please point me to where I can find a complete reference to email headers (Date, From, To, Sender, etc.), if there is one?

Comment: These references are useful, but you might choose to use a 3rd-party control to do the heavy lifting for you.   For example, I used the Chillkat S/MIME control in one project, even though I'm very familiar with email headers, and it saved me a great deal of time and trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might i recommend wikipedia's extensive article on the subject?  The RFC's in the article should answer any questions you may have.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Message_format

Comment: Wonderful, this is just what I needed to get started on this project. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

The core header fields are described in [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322). Futher header fields of MIME are described in [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045) (general headers), [RFC 2046](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046) (media types), and [RFC 2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047) (non-ASCII text).

Answer (score 1):

The full specification can be found in [RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) or (more recent) in [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822).

Comment: You'd need RFC5322 as well.  RF3864 too.